# Table 'dbname.dbname.tablename' doesn't exists error in Visual Studio when adding Mysql Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I am trying to add MySQL with Entity Framework in Visual Studio. I am using MySQL Server 8.0.12 and also the 8.0.12 Connector/MySql.data.
error: MysqlException: Table 'dbname.dbname.tablename' doesn't exists. Normally I have table but dbname name showing twice.

My code's very simple, I want to list all datas in my table:

```
 using (sakilaEntities db = new sakilaEntities())
 {
     var list =  db.country.ToList();
 }
```

I'm getting below error.

[image]

UPDATE: Uninstall MySQL Server 8.0.12 and MySQL Connector 8.0.12 then install MySQL Server&Connector 8.0.19. Add below code in your web config.

```
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Hi, this may be a possible duplicate of [Generating wrong query on Entity Framework 6. Appending table name twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980460/generating-wrong-query-on-entity-framework-6-appending-table-name-twice) or [VS 2019 and MySQL Entity Framework duplicate database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001562/vs-2019-and-mysql-entity-framework-duplicate-database-name). Please check those out and let us know if you find what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

In the generated Model classes, remove the database name. So it should be [Table("Table")] and not [Table("Database.Table")]. Example below:

```
[Table("Owners")]
public partial class Owners
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ListName { get; set; }

    [Column("Owner", TypeName = "text")]
    [StringLength(65535)]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1073741823)]
    public string OwnerProperties { get; set; }
}
```

}