# VS 2019 and MySQL Entity Framework duplicate database name

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, dbconnection

I added Entity Framework to my project but I call the `toList()` method and I'm getting an error:

```
okuldbEntities ent = new okuldbEntities();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ent.ogrenciler.ToList();
}
```

and this is the error:

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External
> Code]
>
> Inner Exception 1: MySqlException: Table
> '**okuldb.okuldb**.ogrenciler' doesn't exist

`okuldb` is my database name and I didn't find why it added it twice.

I looked a lot. I installed VMWare did it all again, but got the same result.

my steps:

1. i download visual studio 2019 community and install it
2. mysql installer and i install mysql server 8.0.22, visual studio connector 1.2.9 and .net connector 8.0.22
3. i create c# project netframework 4.8
4. after this i go nuget package and i install entity framework 6.4.4 and mysql data entityframework 8.0.22 and mysql data 8.0.22
5. after all this i can add entity my project.

i add datagridview1 and i write this code:

```
 eokulEntities ent = new eokulEntities();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ent.ogrencinot.ToList();
        }
```

and i runnig and i see this message:

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]

**Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: Table 'eokul.eokul.ogrencinot' doesn't exist**

i try too much way. i found another laptop i format it and i install again all this.

and again same error.

really what can i do?

Comment: what does your db context code look like?

Comment: in app.config my string:
    <add name="okuldbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=****;database=okuldb&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I was hoping to see the source for `eokulEntities` class - this is the `DbContext` isn't it?

Comment: public partial class eokulEntities2 : DbContext
    {
        public eokulEntities2()
            : base("name=eokulEntities2")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<dersler> dersler { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ogrencibilgi> ogrencibilgi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ogrencinot> ogrencinot { get; set; }
    }

Comment: check if your `ogrenciler` table in MySQL is spelled the same case as in your model?

Comment: no same table name because i try another table and database. same results.

Comment: Use your Shift button once in a while. This goes for your question, as well as your table names. MySQL on Linux is case sensitive in its schema, table and column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Close your visual studio project

2.Edit Model1.edmx file with notepad /or what is the name in your project/

3.Replace matches in file, from Schema="okuldb" to Schema=""

4.Save Model1.edmx file

5.Open visual studio project

6.Compile Project

7.Run Application

Comment: its working thank you but its normal? really why do this i dont understand :/

Comment: Great answer, I'm just wondering why I decided to use mysql in .net

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find any .edmx file in your project. You should find and replace

```
this.ToTable("Table_Name", "Database_Name");
```

With

```
this.ToTable("Table_Name");
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

I found this post

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88507

where a working setup is recommended.

See the section: [30 Aug 2019 2:26] Gerard Ang

The post is about a problem with designer, but it solved ours too.

bye
Claudio