# Generating wrong query on Entity Framework 6. Appending table name twice

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

I am having this error on my Entity Framework using MySQL.

I'm trying to load data to the datagridview.

I tested this using SQL and then it works just fine.

Snippet:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new inventory2Entities().asset_items.ToList();
```

Error:

> MySqlException: Table 'inventory2.inventory2.asset_items' doesn't
> exist

It's duplicating the table name in the query: `inventory2.inventory2`

How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Here is a similar thread: [VS 2019 and MySQL Entity Framework duplicate database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001562/vs-2019-and-mysql-entity-framework-duplicate-database-name). Maybe you can refer to it.

Comment: I already found a solution. I forgot to bookmark the site, they said it was a bug on MySql Connector/Net. Someone suggested to downgrade Connector/Net to 8.0.16 but it work for me on 8.0.17.